# Can I make javascript Image objects interactive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a background image set with CSS to my canvas; it's a map.

I then am "drawing" red pin images on various points on top of the map. Each pin is being drawn as a new Image object with a different name but the same source image.

I want these image pins to be interactive (onMouseOver/onClick/etc), but I am not seeing any event fire when I try and execute the following code:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="backgroundMapCanvas"  width="1177" height="669"></canvas>
</body>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    canvas {
        background:url(images/mapBackground2.jpg)
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("backgroundMapCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var pinMelbourne = new Image();
    pinMelbourne.src = "images/redPin3.png";
    pinMelbourne.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(pinMelbourne, 987, 538);
    };

    pinMelbourne.onmouseover = function() {
        alert("test alert box");
    };
</script>
```

Thanks,

Virat

Comment: You should add your event handlers to the canvas element.

Comment: consider using something like `fabric.js` which provides an object abstraction layer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the event to the canvas object, not the image. The image is drawn on the canvas, but the actual image object is never added to page. To detect if the mouse moves over the image on the canvas, you need to check the bounding box.

```
canvas.addEventListener('movemove', function(e) {
    var x = e.layerX; // x and y coordinated relative to top-left corner of canvas
    var y = e.layerY;
    if (x >= 987 && x < 987 + pinMelbourne.width && y >= 538 && y < 538 + pinMelbourne.height) {
        alert('Mouse over image');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the canvas element.

```
document.getElementById('backgroundMapCanvas').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var x = e.x;
    var y = e.y;

    //ToDo: do something based on where the user clicked
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/86x4cpyh/2/

x and y represent where the user clicked, you can decide how to respond based on that.